# Check a string that MUST contain another string

Tags: javascript, string

I want to check if string `b` is completely contained in string `a`.
I tried:

```
var a = "helloworld";
var b = "wold";
if(a.indexOf(b)) { 
    document.write('yes'); 
} else { 
    document.write('no'); 
}
```

The output is yes, it is not my expected output, because string b(wold) is not completely contained in string a(helloworld) --- wold v.s. world

Any suggestion to check the string?

Comment: related: [Method like String.contains() in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/method-like-string-contains-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the documentation: [MDC String.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) :)

`indexOf` returns the *index* the match was found. This may be 0 (which means "found at the beginning of string") and 0 is a [falsy value](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript).

`indexOf` will return -1 if the needle was not found (and -1 is a [truthy value](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript)). Thus the logic on the test needs to be adjusted to work using these return codes. String found (at beginning or elsewhere): `index >= 0` or `index > -1` or `index != -1`; String not found: `index < 0` or `index == -1`.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `if(a.indexOf(b) > -1)` instead. `indexOf` returns `-1` when it can't find a string.

Answer (score 3):

`.indexOf` returns `-1` if no match was found, which is a *truthy* value. You'll need to check more explicitly:

```
if (a.indexOf(b) != -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `indexOf` returns -1 if a value is not found:

```
if(a.indexOf(b) != -1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use this

```
if(a.indexOf(b) != -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test if the result is -1.  -1 indicates no match, but evaluates to true in a boolean sense.

```
var a = "helloworld";
var b = "wold";
if(a.indexOf(b) > -1) { 
  document.write('yes'); 
} else { 
  document.write('no'); 
}
```